# SQL get latest by date than order by int value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with dates and int value (viewCount), I need to get last 20 rows by date and than sort these rows by viewCount value.

I ended with this but its not ordering by viewCount.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `videos` 
ORDER BY `videos`.`date` DESC, `videos`.`viewCount`  DESC 
limit 20
```

Thanks with help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT v.*
      FROM videos v
      ORDER BY v.date DESC
      LIMIT 20
     ) v
ORDER BY v.viewCount DESC ;
```

Comment: Ahh thanks! Subquery .. need to check this out. Thanks it works!